# Send multiple rows to one recipient based Name

Tags: google-sheets

**Goal:** I want to send an email to the Regionals in charge of the deadlines coming up.

**Issue:** I don't want to send several emails for each row regarding the same Apartments (Apts), but I would like to group the information within the text of the email if the name of the property is the same. If it's not the same name it should stop there and continue to send the email to the recipient.

Open to ideas!

Link to the sheet can be seen [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Js-6RZIjM5IMUb-iOBvpcRU0hv_TKp9RVA7eZvgESHM/edit?usp=sharing) please see script within the sheet to view code.

Comment: Welcome. The sequence of processing, not the code, is the issue. Idea: Change the sequence and add a few extra steps. 1) Build `rowData` **after** evaluating deadline and recipient <> "owner". 2) Add extra "sort" field to `rowData` (concatenate Regional&Property); 3) Build new array of ALL `rowData`; 4) Sort array on "sort" field; 5) Find duplicates of sort field (duplicates combine for one email each); 6) match Regional to email; 7) loop through duplicates, match data in sorted `rowData` array, build message, combine lenderReq fields of duplicates, send one email per duplicate sort code.